# Configure postgresql.conf file through psql command

Tags: database, postgresql, configuration

I want to write a script to configure postgresql.conf file, in which for every parameter it'll show the existing value and after that asked for updated value, then user will enter the updated value.

I'm unable to update the postgresql.conf files parameter through the update command while i can do the alter.
suppose i want to update "shared_preload_libraries" parameter in postgresql.conf which has already some values like

**shared_preload_libraries='$libdir/dbms_pipe,$libdir/edb_gen,$libdir/dbms_aq '**
Now i want to **add 'pgaudit'** like shared_preload_libraries='pgaudit,$libdir/dbms_pipe,$libdir/edb_gen,$libdir/dbms_aq '
i want to do the same through the command

I tried alter command only but it's not the way to update

Answer (score 1):

[Documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/config-setting.html#CONFIG-SETTING-CONFIGURATION-FILE):

> In addition to `postgresql.conf`, a PostgreSQL data directory contains a file `postgresql.auto.conf`, which has the same format as `postgresql.conf` but is intended to be edited automatically, not manually. This file holds settings provided through the [**`ALTER SYSTEM`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altersystem.html) command. This file is read whenever `postgresql.conf` is, and its settings take effect in the same way. Settings in `postgresql.auto.conf` override those in `postgresql.conf`.

You can interact with the config via SQL commands [`SHOW` and `SET`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/config-setting.html#CONFIG-SETTING-SQL-COMMAND-INTERACTION) or functions [`current_setting()` and `set_config()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-SET):

```sql
select set_config('shared_preload_libraries',
                  'pgaudit,'||current_setting('shared_preload_libraries'),
                  false);
```

Unfortunately, in case of [`shared_preload_libraries`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-client.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-CLIENT-PRELOAD) this will fail with `ERROR:  parameter "shared_preload_libraries" cannot be changed without restarting the server`. This type of setting can only be changed directly or through `ALTER SYSTEM SET...`, in case of which the new value will be just saved to `postgresql.auto.conf` until you restart the server because it only applies at startup. If you want to load a library after startup, use [`LOAD`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-load.html).

`ALTER SYSTEM` can't be issued dynamically from functions and [prepared statements](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-prepare.html#id-1.9.3.159.7) or given a function:

```sql
ALTER SYSTEM 
SET shared_preload_libraries = 'pgaudit'
                               || current_setting('shared_preload_libraries');
--ERROR:  syntax error at or near "||"
--LINE 3:                                || current_setting('shared_pr...
--                                       ^

prepare statement1 (text) as 
alter system set shared_preload_libraries to $1; 
execute statement1('pgaudit,'
                   ||current_setting('shared_preload_libraries'));
--ERROR:  syntax error at or near "alter"
--LINE 1: prepare statement1 (text) as alter system set shared_preload...
--                                     ^
do $$
declare current_setting text;
begin
select current_setting('shared_preload_libraries') into current_setting;
current_setting=rtrim(concat_ws(',','pgaudit','test',current_setting),',');
execute format ('alter system set shared_preload_libraries to %s',current_setting);
end $$;
--ERROR:  ALTER SYSTEM cannot be executed from a function
--CONTEXT:  SQL statement "alter system set shared_preload_libraries to pgaudit,test"
--PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 8 at EXECUTE
```

Answer (score 0):

1. First get a copy of `postgresqlconf.sql`.
2. Edit it according to your needs.
3. After building the container, use a shell script or just
   plain commands.

```bash
docker cp ./postgresql.conf
    my-postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data/postgresql.auto.conf

docker restart my-postgres
```

NOTE: `postgresql.auto.conf` is what postgres updates it's `postgresql.conf` from on restart.